# Whenever Goswami's meet, why do they say Aum Namo Narayana?

Tags: belief, history, culture

Whenever two Goswami's meet then why do they say *Aum Namo Narayana*?

Comment: Presumably because they're Vaishnavas, so they say a mantra to Vishnu.

Comment: @Keshav - Not just gosvamis, even shankaracharyas sign off saying Narayana Narayana, only.

Comment: @Krishna What Shankaracharyas sign off with Narayana?  I thought all the Shankaracharyas are Shiva bhaktas nowadays.

Comment: @Keshav - I have seen Kanchi Shankaracharyas sign off as Narayana, Narayana only. Also, many of other Shankaracharyas do the same..

Comment: Sadhus, Sannyasins do the same greeting. We are saluting Narayana in each other.

Comment: @Krishna Aren't the Kanchi Shankaracharyas staunch Shiva bhaktas?

Comment: @Keshav -  they call themselves as advaitins... But, take the name of Narayana, Narayana only. The protocol for advaita Shankara based sanyasis, i suppose.i.e. doing Narayana smaranam

Comment: @Krishna Yeah, they believe in Advaita, and they technically worship the five Panchayatana gods, but in practice they're considered Shaivites, because Shiva is their Ishta Devata.  But yeah, perhaps the tradition of saying Narayana goes back to an earlier time when Advaitins were Vaishnavas.

Comment: @Keshav - Perhaps the earliest advaitins were more vaishnavaite in there practices and leanings, though they ultimately believed in Nirguna brahman, attributeless, nameless, formless etc. Though they might have worshipped many gods, saguna forms Vis- e- Vis Shiva etc, the highest Saguna Brahman was always considered by them as Lord Vishnu.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda By the way, can you take a look at this Brihadaranyaka Upanishad question I just posted: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8616/36

Comment: @Keshav I don't know why you keep getting to the Shankaracharyas are Shiva Bhakta thing. If I am correct Chandrashekhara Saraswati always signed off with Narayana Smritih.

Comment: @Surya Well, I'm just surprised that they'd sign off with a Vishnu-related greeting rather than a Shiva-related greeting.

Comment: @Keshav why discriminate? :)

Comment: Here is an article written by Chandrasekara Saraswathi also knows as Maha Periva of Kanchi titled Namo Namaha. This clearly clarifies the reason. Source: http://www.vedarahasya.net/namonama.htm

Comment: janardana, narayana are names of siva also.