# Where and by who has the Narayana Upanishad been Quoted?

Tags: vishnu, adi-shankaracharya, ramanujacharya, madhvacharya

From what I have heard so far, it is said that the Narayana Upanishad (not to be confused with the Mahanarayana Upanishad of Taittiriya Aranyaka) has been quoted by Shripaada Adi Shankaracharya and Shripaada Ramanujacharya. However, till now, I have not found anyone providing an exact reference of them quoting it. Some say that it has been quoted in Shripaada Adi Shankaracharya's Vishnu-Sahasranama Bhashya, but its authenticity is uncertain and it is also believed to be a similar passage from the Atmabodha Upanishad and not the Narayana Upanishad.

So, my question is: Is the Narayana Upanishad authentic and is there a reference of a reputed saint quoting it before the 15th century, preferably Shripaada Adi Shankaracharya, Shripaada Ramanujacharya or Shripaada Madhvacharya, in works such as Upanishad or Brahma Sutra Bhashyas?

Comment: _Is the Narayana Upanishad authentic_ is opinion based.

Comment: @vivikta Yes, but has it been quoted by scholars before the 13th century? Sri Vaishnavas accept it, but I would like to know, if saints like Shripaada Ramanujacharya quoted it somewhere.

Comment: **Edit:** Sripada Ramanujacharya and Adi Shankaracharya are said to have not referenced the Bhagvatams in their work. Will that make Srimada Bhagavatams inauthentic? No. Similarly. For this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harihi Om.
I discovered the answer to my own question. The Naaraayana Upanishad is authentic and has been quoted several times. Shri Nadadur Ammal (1165-1275 AD), also known as Shri Vatsya Varadacharya, quoted a major portion of the first Khanda of the Naaraayana Upanishad, in [Para-Tattva Nirnaya](https://archive.org/details/paratattvanirnaya/page/n13/mode/2up).[image: Page 22 of Para-Tattva Nirnaya]

Shri Perivachan Pillai, probably the son of Shri Yamunacharya, quoted it in his bhaashya on the Chatushloki.[image: Chatushloki quotation]

It was also quoted by Shri Vedaanta Deshikar, in Taatparya Chandrika, Adhyaaya 10, Shloka 13.

> **नारायणाद्ब्रह्मा जायते नारायणाद्रुद्रो जायते (ना.उ.१)**; क इति ब्रह्मणो नाम ईशोऽहम् सर्वदेहिनाम् । आवाम् तवाङ्गे सम्भूतौ तस्मात्केशव-नामवान् । (ह.वं.१३-४८) इति ब्रह्मरुद्रयोरपि भगवत उत्पन्नतया श्रुति-स्मृत्यवगतत्वात्, स चेति शतमखाद्यपेक्षया पुल्लिङ्गनिर्देशः ।

Further, Shri Ranga Ramanuja Muni quoted it in [his commentary](https://srivaishnavan.com/publications/meghamala/upanishads/svetasvataropanishat-content/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D-part-2/) on the last mantra of the Shvetaashvatara Upanishad.

> ततश्च रुद्र शब्दस्य कार्यरुद्रव्यतिरिक्तविषयत्वे सति, अस्य वाक्यस्य अनुवादरूपतया, 'नारायणाद् ब्रह्मा जायते' इत्यादि योग्यार्थप्रापकवाक्यानुगुण्येन भगवत्परत्वनिश्चयः । रुद्रस्य हिरण्यगर्भजनकत्वाभावेन रूढ्यर्थत्यागे।

Therefore, the Upanishad is authentic and has been quoted by ancient Vedaantins.